# Laravel timestampTz columns have the wrong timezone

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Postgres 13 with Laravel 8.4.4

Setting the Unix timestamp `1607207809` for an Eloquent model property which is defined as cast to datetime, we get the correct Carbon time, `2020-12-05 22:36:49.0 +00:00`.

However, saving this model instance, where that column is defined in the migration as a `timestampTz` column, results in `2020-12-05 22:36:49-08` being saved. This is not the correct timezone, resulting in an incorrect time.

In `config/app.php`, the timezone is set to UTC. My computer's timezone is Pacific Time, so it would appear that is taking precedence somehow. Any ideas why?

I would have expected the timestamp to be saved using the timezone encoded in Carbon, but apparently not?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found is to define `$dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s P'` on the model while casting to datetime.

A custom Cast class (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts) should not be used because when creating a new object, the `created_at` and `updated_at` properties are not yet set.

Without defining `$dateFormat`, the `$value` parameter passed to the Cast class setter for `created_at` and `updated_at` is in the format 'Y-m-d H:i:s'.

This is not a problem if your database server(s) are set to the same timezone as your app, but mistakes happen.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the timezone use by the entire laravel aplication by using `date_default_timezone_set` function to set timezone.

In the `AppServiceProvier` add this code

```
public function boot(){
     date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/xxxxxx');
}
```

Check the name of your timezone here [Pacific Zone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.pacific.php).

Comment: That defeats the purpose of using timestamptz, because the Carbon object might be initialized to a different time zone. What I would like is to have the Carbon object be the source of truth about timezone.

Comment: Additionally, that is still prone to problems on insertion because the Postgres server timezone may differ from the Laravel app. By including the Carbon timezone offset in the insertion query, I believe all possible conflicts that result in accidental timestamp mutation are prevented. Could be wrong about that making everything safe.